# WebStorm - Send an EOF in debugger console

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

The shortcut <kbd>Cmd + D</kbd> works perfectly fine for sending an EOF in the "normal" WebStorm console but it doesn't do anything when I'm debugging my node js script.

I've read the WebStorm documentation, but they only refer to this shortcut...

Do you have any idea what could be the problem or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-16781](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16781) for updates